# show div after 5 seconds and then refresh the div every 1 min

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a div into my page which i wanted to get load after 5 seconds the page get load. Then I wanted to refresh the div without refreshing the page after every 1 min. How can I achieve this functionality with the use of J query. My code look like this

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#newsletter').show();
        }, 100000);

  });
```

This upper block of code is only refreshing the div after 1 min. But on page load , i want the div to be shown to the user after 5 seconds and then this block of code should executed.

Comment: What is the meaning of refreshing the div?

Comment: if you want to load new content into your div without refreshing the whole page, you need to  use Ajax.

Comment: i have a button on that div , when i click that , it get close and then it re-appear after 1 min again, that is the meaning of refreshing the div

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        // Perform actions you need to
        setInterval(function()
        {
            // Perform them again every minute
        }, 60000);

    }, 5000);
});
```

I think what you were looking for is [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
$('#newsletter').show(); // to show div after 5 sec of page load

// To reshow on every one minute
setInterval(function() {
            $('#newsletter').show();
        }, 60000);
  }, 5000);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the base functionality there, so all you'll need to do is add a message to appear after 5 seconds. Something like this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
   setTimeout(function() { 
          // show message
      },5000);

     setInterval(function() {
        $('#newsletter').show();
    }, 60000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $newsletter = $('#newsletter')
        .delay(5000)
        .show(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                // update the newsletter, e.g. set new text
                $newsletter.text(new Date());
            }, 60000);
        });
});
```